# How do you open the Dark Palace without paying Kiki?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

The first dungeon in the Dark World is the Dark Palace, as you approach the Palace a little monkey-type creature called Kiki starts following you, if you give him 10 rupees. Once you get to the entrance to the Dark Palace he offers to open it for you for 100 rupees.

[image: Kiki opening the Dark Palace]

You are also given the opportunity during this conversation to "try and do it yourself". Is it possible to open the Dark Palace without paying Kiki rupees, if so - how would you achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there is no other way of entering the palace without paying Kiki:

> Kiki will agree to accompany Link to the Palace of Darkness for a payment of ten Rupees; this must be paid, as Link cannot enter the palace without Kiki's help. When they reach the dungeon entrance, Kiki will open it for Link in exchange for 100 Rupees.

Source [here](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Palace_of_Darkness)

Answer (score 2):

I have completed A Link To The Past and the only way to get in is to pay Kiki. The best way to get rupees is to cut tall grass, that gives out blue or red ones.

Answer (score -2):

You gotta pull on the door for 4 minutes and 28 seconds with your power glove, and then use ether, and it should open. If not, then Try like a bunch of bombs. That's what I did.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source for your answer?  It directly contradicts the accepted answer.